# HTTP post multipart-form data length format?

Tags: http, post, content-type

In a HTTP POST multipart-form content-type stream, what do the long ------------- lines means? What is hex encoded as the end of these lines? Can you figure out the length of the variables from them? Or is this a specially designed sequence so you can find the break between variables?

```
-----------------------------7dc34719970524 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="my variable" 

blah content here
-----------------------------7dc34719970524 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="asdfasdf"

heaps of data here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a boundary that is used to separate the different sets of data in case of a multi-part data submission. Read more about it:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

To quote from the link:

> In the case of multiple part messages, in which one or more different sets of data are combined in a single body, a "multipart" Content-Type field must appear in the entity's header. **The body must then contain one or more "body parts," each preceded by an encapsulation boundary, and the last one followed by a closing boundary**. Each part starts with an encapsulation boundary, and then contains a body part consisting of header area, a blank line, and a body area. Thus a body part is similar to an RFC 822 message in syntax, but different in meaning.